# Sending multiple e-mails asynchronously in quick succession

Tags: c#, email, asp.net-core, asynchronous

I am developing a Web application with ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1, using Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition, Version 16.8.0 (updated on 11/11/2020).

In this application, an administrator can enter users into a database. Whenever a user is entered, an e-mail message is sent in the background to that user. To prevent a delay in the displaying of the confirmation page, the e-mail message is sent asynchronously. This works fine, except when the administrator enters several users in quick succession. Then only one or two of the messages get sent, because the e-mail server imposes a limit on the number of threads that can be used simultaneously.

If anyone could tell me how to deal with this problem, I would appreciate it.

Here is some background on my current code:

First of all, there is a function for inserting a user into the database. If the insertion succeeds, this function calls another function, which sends the new user an e-mail message.

The insertion function has the following pattern:

```
    void InsertUser(...)
    {
        // Insertion code here
    
        // If operation successful:
        Task t = SendGreetingsAsync(...);
    }
```

As you can see, InsertUser(...) does not "await" SendGreetingsAsync(...). If it did, the benefit of asynchronicity would be lost. At least, that is my understanding.

SendGreetingsAsync(...) calls a function SendGreetings(...) like this:

```
    async Task SendGreetingsAsync(...)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        SendGreetings(...);
    }
```

SendGreetings(...) is a synchronous function on the following pattern:

```
    void SendGreetings(...)
    {
        // Send an e-mail to the user specified in the parameter list
    }
```

To recapitulate, the issue is how to prevent display delays due to background e-mail messaging when several users are entered in quick succession, without causing problems on the e-mail end.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you are sending emails - you need to store them somewhere, to be able to retry. There are absolutely valid reasons for SMTP server to temporary reject your email, besides one you encountered, in which case you have to retry later. Or you can use proper SMTP server which does that for you. Sending emails from web application in "fire and forget" fashion is very unreliable.

Comment: Thank you for this advice and for responding so promptly. Could you please explain how to "use proper SMTP server which does that for you"?

Answer (score 0):

Use [SemaphoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=net-5.0) to limit concurrency through a code path.

```
async Task SendGreetingsAsync(...)
{
    try 
    {
      await semaphore.WaitAsync();
      SendGreetings(...);
    }
    finally
    {
      semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Or add the emails to a [BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/blockingcollection-overview) and have a single background thread send all the emails.

Comment: Thank you very much, David. I'll read up on these tools, which I had never heard of before.